# Count rows matching criteria for every row in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Hi here is a sample spreadsheet:

```
+--------+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| Animal | Count | Animal Type | Animal Type Count |
+--------+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| cat    |     1 | cat         |                 3 |
| cat    |     2 | dog         |                 4 |
| dog    |     4 | turtle      |                 5 |
| turtle |     5 |             |                   |
+--------+-------+-------------+-------------------+
```

I created Animal Type dynamically:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE("A2:A")))
```

But I am stuck on how to create the fourth column dynamically. I tried mixing `COUNT`, `COUNTIF`, and `FILTER`. But examples I have seen so far always hardcode the filter/search criteria.

How would I build something similar to what I think in psudeocode?

```
animal_types = [for row in Columns['Animal Type']]
animal_types_count = {}
for animal_type in animal_types:
    for row in Rows:
        if row['Animal'] == animal_type:
            animal_types_count[animal_type] += row['count']
```

Comment: @fixer1234 This is not off-topic. Actually, Google spreadsheet has almost all the functions Excel has. If ``UNIQUE`` and ``SORT`` do not exist in Excel that's just my lack of usage with Excel, but this question is still very much valid in Excel. In fact I plan to export from Google server; if I don't have Excel handy I will use an online tool. The core question does not change. So no, off topic is the wrong thing.

Comment: Google Spreadsheet is very similar to Excel, but as a web app, it is off-topic.  In general, there is no guarantee that a solution in one will work in the other, and it would be detrimental if users came looking for solutions and found they didn't always work because some are peculiar to a different app.  In this case, you asked for a solution to an Excel problem for use later in Excel, so it won't be a problem for other users.  But it complicated matters when you tried to implement it in Google Spreadsheet, which sort of illustrates the problem.  I'll retract the close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel does not have a Sort nor a Unique function. I fail to see how you make that work. But if you have that working, however you do it, you can use a simple Sumif to add up all the numbers for the animals

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$5,C2,$B$2:$B$5)
```

Copy down.

[image]

Or you could use a pivot table on the original data. Four clicks. No formulas.

[image]

Comment: @telyyn thanks I am actually using Google Spreadsheet (but I plan to export to my computer), I did not know ``UNIQUE`` and ``SORT`` don't exist in Excel. So there is no real way to build column D more dynamically? It seems like in option 1 I am really telling the forum look at C2, C3, C4, etc"

Comment: Make up your mind. You can't use one product and ask a question about another. Excel and Google spreadsheet are not the same. And, Yes, there IS a way to build column D (and C) dynamically in Excel. Use a Pivot Table, as I have shown above. Refresh the pivot table when you add more data to the data source. I don't understand what you mean with "I am realy telling the forum look at C2, C3" etc. What forum?

Comment: thanks but "make up my mind" is little unncessary. See my comment above and I don't want to argue on public forum with someone who helped me. Forum is a typo, I meant column. I will try Pivot Table, thanks!